# Calculating the unconditional expectation of an Ito process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that:
$$dX_t =\mu(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t,$$
where $X_t$ is a vector valued stochastic process, $W_t$ is a vector of Brownian motions, $\mu$ is a vector valued function and $\sigma$ is a matrix valued function.

I want to compute the unconditional expectation $\mathbb{E}X_t$ defined by:
$$\mathbb{E}X_t := \lim_{s\rightarrow -\infty}{\mathbb{E}[X_t|X_s=0]}.$$
(Assume that this quantity is guaranteed to be well-defined and finite for the particular $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of interest.)

It seems that it is at least true that:
$$\frac{d\mathbb{E}X_t}{dt}=\mathbb{E}\mu(t,X_t)?$$
(See: [How to find mean of a stochastic differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781694/how-to-find-mean-of-a-stochastic-differential-equation) . So, I take it no extra term can enter coming from some kind of instantaneous correlation between $\sigma(t,X_t)$ and $dW_t$.)

Are there any tricks to simplify evaluating $\mathbb{E}\mu(t,X_t)$? Applying Ito's lemma to get the law of motion for $\mu(t,X_t)$ is unlikely to help as that LOM will have a new drift term.

When $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are non-linear, is there any hope of deriving a solution for $\mathbb{E}X_t$ in terms of an ODE?

Does the problem simplify much if $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are not directly functions of $t$?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such technique in general, hence a case-by-case treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, if you can solve the corresponding [Fokker-Plank equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation), then yes. The sde

$$dX_t = \mu(X_t, t) \,dt + \sigma(X_t, t) \,dW_t$$

corresponds to the pde

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x, t) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\mu(x, t) p(x, t)\right] + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left[D(x, t) p(x, t)\right],$$

for $D(X_t, t) = \sigma^2(X_t, t)/2$. So $E[\mu(t,X_{t})]=\int \mu(t,y)p(y,t)dy.$ But often those pdes don't have closed form solutions.